# Magento 2: Customer details change to another when edited in grid row

Tags: magento2, customer-address, magento-2.1.2, customer-grid

I seem to be having a strange problem with my Magento 2 installation and wanted to know if anyone else has come across this issue and may point me in the right direction towards a possible cause and therefore solution.

So, the issue seems to occur when I edit a customer in the customer grid. When I make a change, the customers address and company details change to that of another customer (seemingly at random), however when I go in to edit the customer the address details are as they should be, I tick the 'set as default' for billing and shipping, save the customer and the details then appear correctly.

If I then make another change in the grid row to that customer, the details again change to that of a different customer (although always to the same one that they did before) and the same story, the default addresses have been unticked, I make the changes and save them and it is fine again.

I appreciate this may be a little hard to imagine, so I have some screenshots to show this happening.

The customer as they should be:
[image: Customer Before]

The customer after I have made a grid action / inline grid row change:
[image: Customer After]

It's important to note that no details actually get changed to the customer, it just appears wrong in the customer grid.

I am going through the process of testing what's gone wrong with a fresh Magento 2 installation, and hopefully this might lead to some explanations.

I am thinking this may have had something to do with the fact I imported data from a Magento 1 installation using Ubertheme's Data Migration tool.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

many thanks.